# How can we count in base eleven?

Tags: number-systems

We work in base 10. We know base 3 would count 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20. How would we count in base 11?

Comment: You know how counting in Hexadecimal is done right? It could be done similarly with just the A included.Leave out the other alphabets.

Comment: Use the symbol "A" to represent 10.  So you get $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,10,11,12,...$

Comment: @CSCFCEM: Check your counting!

Comment: It doesn't need to be "A". For example, it could be "T", for "ten". I doubt there's one standard way.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to add a symbol for $10$, such as $A$. Then it would be
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\text{Base 10} & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & 9 & 10 & 11 \\ \hline
\text{Base 11} & 1 & 2 & 3 & \dots & 9 & A & 10 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 2):

Typically one would write a special symbol that represents ten, say, $A$. Then, the first few natural numbers in base eleven would be written as

$$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 1A, 20, 21$$

and so on. In this system,

- the quantity one hundred would be written as $91$,
- the quantity one hundred and nine would be written as $9A$, and
- the quantity one hundred ten would be written as $A0$,
- the quantity one hundred twenty would be written as $AA$, and
- the quantity one hundred twenty-one would be written as $100$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the symbol "A" to represent 10.  So you get $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,A,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,1A,20,\dots$

Answer (score 1):

base $2$  we only have two digits $0,1$

base $10$ we have $10$ digits $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$

base $11$ we would have $11$ digits $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\beta$

where $\beta$ is a new digit

Answer (score -1):

You know how counting in Hexadecimal is done right? It could be done similarly with just the A included.Leave out the other alphabets.